# How to zeroize an objective-c object under ARC

Tags: objective-c, security

How do I zeroize an objective-c object (for security purposes) before deallocation (using ARC)?

Comment: What kind of object? Your object or a Foundation object like `NSNumber` or `NSString`?

Comment: Many of the Framework objects like NSString are immutable.  You can't  clear them.

Comment: Or, are you just wanting to set an object to nil?

Comment: just zero the memory after an object has been deallocated.. same as before ARC

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this (other than in classes you control, obviously).  Zeroing after deallocation would be impossibly dangerous, even if you could somehow determine where all the pieces of the object are stored.

Comment: (And one is a bit curious as to how zeroing could improve security, given that the object was accessible to the entire app *before* you decided to deallocate it.)

Comment: You can still use dealloc in arc to do some cleanup just not the [super dealloc] part

Comment: I was thinking NSString... Daji-Djan seem to give an interesting answer. If I keep a pointer to an object and its size, then after deallocation I could memset that memory to zero right?

Comment: Submit a bug report to Apple requesting a secure `NSString`,I have. http://bugreporter.apple.com It possible to subclass NSString and write a secure zeroing version.

Comment: More like a zeroizable NSObject ... that way we'll have the feature in all classes